# Writing data from parallel to serial port

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, serial-port, parallel-port

We wrote a program that sends simple data from LPT1 to RS232C. Basically, LPT to Serial converted cable is used to hook two machines together. The program has no issue writing data to the parallel port, but nothing is received on the serial end.

I'm wondering if such communication is possible on a fundamental level or I've wrote my program incorrectly.

DataSender (Write to LPT1)

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

        HANDLE m_hCommPort = ::CreateFile( "LPT1",
       GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,  // access ( read and write)
       0,                           // (share) 0:cannot share the
                                    // COM port
       0,                           // security  (None)
       OPEN_EXISTING,               // creation : open_existing
       FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,        // we want overlapped operation
       0                            // no templates file for
                                    // COM port...
       );


        if(m_hCommPort) {
            printf("OK\n");
        }
        char data[] = "123481278349789\r\n";
        DWORD dwSize = strlen(data);
        DWORD dwBytesWritten;
        DWORD dwBytesRead;

        while(true) {

        if(WriteFile (m_hCommPort,data,dwSize,&dwBytesWritten ,0)) {
            printf("sended: %d\n", dwBytesWritten);
        } else {
            printf("send fail: %d\n", dwBytesWritten);
        }

        printf("send done\n");

        int i;
        scanf("%d", &i);
        }
        return 0;

}
```

DataReceiver (Receive from COM3)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort sendingPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);
        try
        {
            sendingPort.Open();
            char c = (char)sendingPort.ReadChar();

            Console.WriteLine("Readed:" + c);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that there is "no issue writing data to the parallel port" ?  Does the first program ever pause, what is the output?

Comment: Program doesn't pause. WriteFile returns true with the length of the bytes written, so I'm assuming it is working

Comment: And roughly, how many lines per second?

Comment: And describe "LPT to Serial converted cable" better. There is a piece of electronics in there, right? With LEDs? How is it powered?

Comment: For the cable, check the following image: http://tinyurl.com/lpj5qy9

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by how many lines per second. I press any key to send data (since scanf is blocking) in however fashion I desire

Comment: I didn't spot that the scanf was inside the while(true). You can/should fix indentation when posting.

Comment: That's a 25-to-9 cable, and unless there a big bobble in the middle it's not a converter.